# saved images from kinect are black

Tags: kinect, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I tried to save the images received from Kinect as png. I picked up a kinect sample from the package, which shows both depth and color picture on two planes and I modify them. I tried different approaches like saving the color32 directly or transferring it to another texture but none worked. Note I can see both images displayed on two planes in Unity scene. Here is the code that I have to save the image.

```
void Update () {

    if (kinect.pollColor())
    {
        tex.SetPixels32(mipmapImg(kinect.getColor(),640,480));
        // Code by me to save the image
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes("screenshots/testscreen-" + imageCount + ".png", bytes);
        imageCount++;
        //
        tex.Apply(false);
    }
}

private Color32[] mipmapImg(Color32[] src, int width, int height)
{
    int newWidth = width / 2;
    int newHeight = height / 2;
    Color32[] dst = new Color32[newWidth * newHeight];
    for(int yy = 0; yy < newHeight; yy++)
    {
        for(int xx = 0; xx < newWidth; xx++)
        {
            int TLidx = (xx * 2) + yy * 2 * width;
            int TRidx = (xx * 2 + 1) + yy * width * 2;
            int BLidx = (xx * 2) + (yy * 2 + 1) * width;
            int BRidx = (xx * 2 + 1) + (yy * 2 + 1) * width;
            dst[xx + yy * newWidth] = Color32.Lerp(Color32.Lerp(src[BLidx],src[BRidx],.5F),
                                                   Color32.Lerp(src[TLidx],src[TRidx],.5F),.5F);
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

I added three lines to the sample code, which I marked by the comments in the Update function. I also tried changing Update to LateUpdate but nothing changed.

Comment: If you try logging any of the values from `Color32[] src`, do you get back expected colour values (basically not all 0,0,0)?

Comment: No the are not all 0s. And I mapped the textures (One picture and one depth) to two planes and I can see the image on the planes.

Comment: Hm...how about logging for the values you're retrieving as you iterate through the array? What range of values are you getting back for TLidx, TRidx, BLidx, BRidx? Also varying between 0-255?

Comment: @Serlite The values are not between 0-255. I get something like this: 247040 247041  247680  247681.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kinect sample code was creating texture like this:

```
tex = new Texture2D(320,240,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
```

changing it to:

```
tex = new Texture2D(320,240,TextureFormat.RGB24,false);
```

Solved the problem.
In the this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/352/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html) it claims that the EncodeToPNG function will work on both ARGB32 and RGB24, but it seems this is not the case!